# Проблема с исключением NameError

Tags: python-3.x, исключения, print

Есть такой код, который считает символы в переданой строке. Но у меня почему-то не получается поймать исключение с неймерором - когда я передаю не строку.

```
def count_chars(word): 
try:
        a = {}  
        for w in word: 
            a[w] = word.count(w)
        for k in sorted(a):
            print (k + ': ' + str(a[k]))
except NameError:
    print('False')
```

Вот к примеру - когда пробую вывести такое : `print(count_chars(gjkgaorrwww))` - получаю `NameError: name is not defined`.

Вчера пробовал сделать через `type`, вроде получилось, но потом случайно стёр. 
Было что-то такого плана:

```
def count_symbols(word):
    if type(word) is not str:
        print('False')
    else:
        a = {}  
        for w in word: 
            a[w] = word.count(w)
        for k in sorted(a):
            print (k + ': ' + str(a[k]))
```

но сейчас вывод тоже дает `NameError`.

Понимаю, что это очень тупой вопрос и разгадка где-то на поверхности - но уже все перепробовал, не понимаю в чем проблема.

Comment: По сути `NameError` - это сигнал о логической ошибке в программе. Это исключение не нужно пытаться отловить, а нужно исправлять программу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь ввести что-то такое:

```
print(count_chars(gjkgaorrwww))
```

то логично ожидать, что создастся исключение `NameError`, если переменная с названием `gjkgaorrwww` не определена. Обращаетесь вы к ней перед вызовом функции (так как для вызова функция необходимо её передать), поэтому блок try-except внутри функции её и не поймает.
Можно сделать так:

```
try:
    count_chars(gjkgaorrwww)
except NameError:
    print(...)
```

Но какого поведения вы хотите от вашей программы?

Comment: Я хочу, чтобы в случае передачи неправильных данных функция не показывала ошибку, а выводила `False`. Или с буквенными данными не получится?

Спасибо, сейчас попробую Ваш вариант.

Comment: @АнатолійАндрійович что вы подразумеваете под неправильными данными? Несуществующую переменную или переменную не того типа?

Comment: Переменную не того типа. В данном случае - любую переменную отличного от `String` типа.

Comment: @АнатолійАндрійович ну тогда ваш второй вариант сейчас и так работает. Попробуйте передать туда, например, число и убедитесь.

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо, я как-то не подумав что все буквенные данные будут считаться переменными.  

Тогда вопрос закрыт, извиняюсь за тупняк.

Answer (score 0):

Вижу вы хотите вывести кол-во всех символов, зачем же делать это таким образом?

Можно сделать это так:

```
In [21]: from collections import Counter

In [22]: string = 'Python its grate!'

In [23]: Counter(string)
Out[23]:
Counter({' ': 2,
         '!': 1,
         'P': 1,
         'a': 1,
         'e': 1,
         'g': 1,
         'h': 1,
         'i': 1,
         'n': 1,
         'o': 1,
         'r': 1,
         's': 1,
         't': 3,
         'y': 1})
```

Функция может выглядеть так:

```
In [39]: def symbols(string):
    ...:     if type(string) == str:
    ...:         return Counter(string)
    ...:     return False
```

Или `lambda`:

```
In [42]: foo = lambda string: Counter(string) if type(string) == str else False
```